# Facebook 'like' widget displays in Firefox. Not Safari?

Tags: html, facebook, widget

Just a quick one to see if anyone has had any experience of this, and/or could suggest what it might be.

Displays the facebook like widget in the footer in Firefox... but not in Safari.

Does anybody know why? I imagine it's nothing major!

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cache and check if Javascript is enabled.Facebook widgets require Javascript to be enabled.

Comment: Hi - cache is clear and javascript is definately enabled. it appears to be more of a cross-browser issue perhaps?

Comment: can you confirm if the facebook like widget displays in the footer?

Comment: @BNewton.co.uk ,i am  really sorry,i don't click on external links

Comment: ah no worries. Basically the facebook like widget appears in ALL browsers except Safari...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to re-install your widget.sometimes even the css make a role